# Can I extend a C# Enum so I can get its value formatted in more than one way?

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I have the following Enum:

```
public enum ContentKey {
    Menu = 0,
    Article = 1,
    Topic = 2
};
```

When I use the Enum I have been doing the following:

```
((int)ContentKey.Topic).ToString("D2")
```

Is there some way that I could create an extension to the Enum so I didn't have to code the above?

Comment: Your expression doesn't compile, so that's *not* what you've "been doing". Can you give a compilable example of what you've "been doing", or just describe what result it is that you're attempting to obtain?

Comment: Hi Damien. Here's the code: var pk = "00" +
 ((int) ContentKey.Topic.ToString("D2")) + "000"; It compiles okay for me.

Comment: Really? - because I get an error "cannot convert type `string` to `int`" when I copy and paste that into a fresh console application.

Comment: I'm very sorry. You are correct. It should be o((int)ContentKey.Topic).ToString("D2") Thanks for your advice. I copy pasted the wrong code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use extension methods:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static string ToFormattedString(this ContentKey key, string format)
    {
        //do staff
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ContentKey.Topic.ToFormattedString("D2")
```